# Identifying the column that has the lowest value

Tags: r

I have a data frame given by the following

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 129, 169, 1087), `Collab Years Patents` = c(NA, 
"2011, 2011, 2011", "2010", "2006, 2006"), `Collab Years Publications` = c("2011", 
"2015, 2016, 2016", "2010", NA), ECP = c("2011", "2011", "2010", 
"2006")), .Names = c("ID", "Collab Years Patents", "Collab Years Publications", 
"ECP"), row.names = c(1L, 107L, 136L, 859L), class = "data.frame")
```

The column ECP is the minimum year of the two collaboration columns (which could contain several years). I need an output that says which column the ECP belongs to. For example, a solution to above could be another column vector to above frame with the elements:

```
    structure(list(ID = c(1, 129, 169, 1087), `Collab Years Patents` = c(NA, 
"2011, 2011, 2011", "2010", "2006, 2006"), `Collab Years Publications` = c("2011", 
"2015, 2016, 2016", "2010", NA), ECP = c("2011", "2011", "2010", 
"2006"), identifier = c("Publications", "Patents", "Both", "Patents"
)), .Names = c("ID", "Collab Years Patents", "Collab Years Publications", 
"ECP", "identifier"), row.names = c(1L, 107L, 136L, 859L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I've updated the question to display the answer. The solution column (in my example "identifier") will be a 3 factor column that represents either of the "Collab" columns or says "both" when both have the minimum ECP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `str_detect`.  Loop through the collaboration columns (`sapply(DF[2:3],`), use `str_detect` to check which one of the column have the value of 'ECP'.  multiply by `col` to convert the TRUE values to the column index, replace the `NA` elements with 0, get the column names correspond based on the maximum column index, remove the prefix part of the column names with `sub`, and assign those elements in 'm1' that are greater than 0 i.e. have 'ECP' in both to 'Both' on the created vector 'v1'

```
library(stringr)
m1 <- col(DF[2:3]) *sapply(DF[2:3], function(x) str_detect(x, DF$ECP))
m1[is.na(m1)] <- 0
v1 <- sub(".*\\s(\\w+)$", "\\1", names(DF)[2:3][max.col(m1)])
v1[rowSums(m1 > 0) ==2] <- "Both"
DF$identifier <- v1
DF$identifier
#[1] "Publications" "Patents"      "Both"         "Patents"
```

Comment: That was so fast an answer. You are awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` (`dplyr` and `purrr`):

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  mutate_at(2:3,strsplit,", ") %>%
  transmute(identifier = pmap(.[2:4],~c("Publications","Patents","Both")[
    2*(..3 %in% .x) + (..3 %in% .y)])) %>%
  bind_cols(DF,.)

#     ID Collab Years Patents Collab Years Publications  ECP   identifier
# 1    1                 <NA>                      2011 2011 Publications
# 2  129     2011, 2011, 2011          2015, 2016, 2016 2011      Patents
# 3  169                 2010                      2010 2010         Both
# 4 1087           2006, 2006                      <NA> 2006      Patents
```